# Extract values row-wise from a dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have **a dataframe** which has 15 columns. All values are numeric.

I have **a vector** having numeric values ranging from 1 to 15. Lets say x = c( 5,7,2,8,13,5,6...).

From each row in the dataframe, I need to get a value from a column, such that column corresponds to the vector value.

For example, using vector x,  from the first row pull the 5th value, from 2nd row pull 7th, then for 3rd row the 2nd column etc..

PS: I'm nowhere in this

Comment: `data[cbind(x,1:15)]` is what you are looking for

Comment: @Onyambu Hi Thanks. But I think its data[cbind(1:nrow(data),x)]

Comment: I see.. you meant `x` is the columns.. Sure sure you are right

Answer (score 1):

For any one interested:

```
data[ cbind(1:nrow(data), x) ]
```

Where data is our data frame with 15 columns